# What does not having a first-order frame imply for models?

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic, incompleteness, modal-logic

There are formulas in modal logic which which *do not have a first-order frame condition*, as stated [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sahlqvist_formula#Examples_of_non-Sahlqvist_formulas) (Non-Sahlqvist formulas, Wikipedia). 
An example is the McKinsey formula for $p$:

$$\Box\,\Diamond\,p\rightarrow \Diamond\,\Box\,p$$

"*If it's necessary that it's possible that $p$, then it's possible that it's necessary that p.*"

What exactly does not having a first-order frame frame mean for models of theories that contains such statements. Does this this just mean we can't replace the modal language with a first-order language, or is it more severe? If there are models, what's a simple example for a theory of some things or a situation for which the formula holds.

I'm interested in modal operators because I've seen them popping up in a form of their categorical models. Regarding this question, is there an argument to add modal operators to our formal language - it's curious how they don't seem to be used much outside of philosphy and I try to find out if it's because the relevant notions they can express are captured by the standard language anyway.

Comment: You can see also this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266285/prove-that-diamond-box-p-rightarrow-diamond-box-p-land-q-lor-boxp-lan) for a related example.

Answer (score 2):

You can see :

- James Garson, [Modal Logic for Philosophers](https://books.google.it/books?id=rFpbAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA209) (2006), **Ch.10 : Axioms and Their Corresponding Conditions on $R$**, page 209-on.

> we will prove a theorem that may be used to determine conditions on $R$ from axioms (and vice versa) for a wide range of axioms (Lemmon and Scott, 1977). (For a more general result of this kind see Sahlqvist, 1975 $[1]$.)
>
> The theorem concerns axioms that have the form :
>
> > (G) $\ \ \Diamond^h \Box^i A \rightarrow \Box^j \Diamond^k A.$
>
> The notation ‘$\Diamond^n$’ represents $n$ diamonds in a row, so, for example, ‘$\Diamond^3$’ abbreviates: $\Diamond \Diamond \Diamond$. Similarly, ‘$\Box^n$’ represents a string of $n$ boxes. When the values of $h,i,j$, and $k$ are all $1$, we have axiom :
>
> > (C) $\ \ \Diamond \Box A \rightarrow \Box \Diamond A.$
>
> The axiom (B) results from setting $h$ and $k$ to $0$, and letting $j$ and $k$ be 1.
>
> > (B) $\ \ A \rightarrow \Box \Diamond A.$
>
> To obtain (4), we may set $h$ and $k$ to $0$, set $i$ to $1$ and $j$ to $2$.
>
> > (4) $\ \ \Box A \rightarrow \Box \Box A.$

[...]

> It is interesting to see how the diagrams for the familiar conditions on $R$ result from setting the values for $h, i, j$, and $k$ according to the values in the corresponding axiom [page 213].

For (B), we have that the condition on $R$ amounts to *symmetry* that, as per your Wiki's reference, can be expressed with condition on the relation $R$ in first-order language : $\forall w_1 \forall w_2(w_1Rw_2 \rightarrow w_2Rw_1)$.

For (4), it amounts to *transitivity*, i.e. $\forall w_1 \forall w_2 \forall w_3(w_1Rw_2 \land w_2Rw_3 \rightarrow w_1Rw_3)$.

For :

> > (D) $\ \ \Box A \rightarrow \Diamond A$

we have *seriality* : $\forall w_1 \exists w_2 (w_1Rw_2)$.

---

For McKinsey formula see :

- Patrick Blackburn & Maarten de Rijke & Yde Venema, [Modal Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=pbb_Asgoq0oC&pg=PA133) (2002), page 133 :

> **Example 3.11** We will show that the McKinsey formula $□◊p → ◊□p$ does not correspond to a first-order condition by showing that it violates the Lowenheim-Skolem theorem.

---

$[1]$ Henrik Sahlqvist, *Completeness and Correspondence in First and Second-Order Semantics for Modal Logic*, in Stig Kanger (editor), [Proceedings of the Third Scandinavian Logic Symposium](https://books.google.it/books?id=RF-vAAAAIAAJ&dq=editions:va203AvBa00C&hl=it&redir_esc=y) (1975), page 110-on.

Comment: Is this answer about the models for sentences such as the McKinsey formula? I don't quite understand.

Comment: @NikolajK - according to Wiki, McKinsey formula is "Non-Sahlqvist", i.e. it is not possible to find a corresponding first-order formula for $R$; Wiki's reference for this result is : L.A.Chagrova, [An undecidable problem in correspondence theory](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jsl/1183743813) (1991).